# Suitable approach for serving HLS playlist from GCP using node.js server

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, http-live-streaming, vod

I have a dilemma in serving dynamic hls playlists to users, since all hls files will have to be served from GCP storage. Since index file is static, I can simply serve it using express static as outlined in one answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878178/hls-streaming-using-node-js) but it is limited to file directory (in my opinion). For streaming HLS playlist from GCP, I tried the following approach

For serving dynamic index files from GCP

```
router.get('/segments-list', (req, res) => {
  const playlistName = req.query;
  const remoteFile = hlsPlaylistBucket.file('${playlistName}.m3u8'); 
  remoteFile.download().then((data) => {
    const contents = data[0];
    res.send(contents);
  });
});
```

For serving individual segment files (.ts) to users

```
router.get('/segments/:segment', (req, res) => {
  const { segment } = req.params;
  //* Gets specific segment files from GCP cloud in request of particular segments
  const remoteFile = hlsPlaylistBucket.file(`${segment}`);

  remoteFile.download().then((data) => {
    const contents = data[0];
    res.send(contents);
  });
});
```

Here is the manifest file

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:8.341667,
segments/file000.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
segments/file001.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
segments/file002.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
segments/file003.ts
#EXTINF:5.572233,
segments/file004.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Now this approach seems to work but this is a flawed approach due to downloading small chunks for files in memory every time user requests. And serving signed urls for each segment files is also not a suitable way was well as one video might contain 200 segments files. Is my approach correct or do I have to serve HLS playlists like [this](https://hlsbook.net/how-to-serve-hls-video-from-an-s3-bucket/#comment-111) in GCP. The real problem arises in serving base url segments files and I have been stuck for the past couple of days in this problem but I cannot find a suitable way to serve VOD file to users by serving HLS playlist
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option here is to serve them from a GCP bucket using CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing), here you can find a guide on how to configure CORS for a GCP bucket [1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#configure-cors-bucket).

Even further, you could render the conversion and packaging of the original video files to the Transcoder API Google service [2](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/concepts/overview), which can generate and store the HLS manifest and files into a GCP bucket, to later be used by any Video Streaming Player, take a look at this Quickstart guide [3](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/quickstart).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although atm it wont be possible for me to incorporate changes due to time constraint so I have tweaked my approach from downloading to streaming each file segment, although it works atm but in future I shall follow your suggestion for a more streamlined approach

Comment: Can I help you with other information? If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark (✔️) on the left side under the vote arrows. Should change the color to green.